# Format list of numbers as fixed-width array and write to file

Tags: python, file, formatting, dataset, fixed-width

**Problem Statement:**

I need to take a list of numbers (of any precision), format them into scientific notation, and write them to a text file of 5 columns, filling one full row at a time. The numbers need to be formatted so that the overall file format is essentially fixed-width. Use of Numpy, SciPy, Pandas, or other libraries is acceptable.

**Motivation:**

This fixed-width file format is extremely common in earthquake ground-motion time history datasets. Certain software programs that utilize ground motions as input only take files of this exact format. An quick and elegant answer on how to write ordinate values from an equally-spaced ground motion time histories into this format will serve the geophysics community.

**Sample Dataset:**

```
lst = [-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**Expected Text File Output:**

```
-0.90000e+01  -0.80000e+01  -0.70000e+01  -0.60000e+01  -0.50000e+01
-0.40000e+01  -0.30000e+01  -0.20000e+01  -0.10000e+01   0.00000
 0.10000e+01   0.20000e+01   0.30000e+01   0.40000e+01   0.50000e+01
 0.60000e+01   0.70000e+01   0.80000e+01   0.90000e+01   0.10000e+02
```

**Attempt:**

```
lst = [-9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

lst_e = list(map("{:.5e}".format, lst))

for i in range(0, len(lst_e), 5):
    print('  '.join(lst_e[i:i+5]))
```

**Attempt Output:**

```
-9.00000e+00  -8.00000e+00  -7.00000e+00  -6.00000e+00  -5.00000e+00
-4.00000e+00  -3.00000e+00  -2.00000e+00  -1.00000e+00  0.00000e+00
1.00000e+00  2.00000e+00  3.00000e+00  4.00000e+00  5.00000e+00
6.00000e+00  7.00000e+00  8.00000e+00  9.00000e+00  1.00000e+01
```

Comment: do you need it to be `-0.9000000e+01` or is `-9.00000e+00` also acceptable as it is easier to implement?

Comment: Both formats work.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. This is not homework--it's related to personal research. There isn't a straightforward guideline or resource that I can easily find in StackOverflow or elsewhere on the internet about how to format numbers using Python in the way I've described. This is obviously a trivial problem to solve if brute-forced, but there is no truly Pythonic way to accomplish that I've been able to find. As such, there is merit in having this question, at the very least, act as a guideline for people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can get convert a float to a scientific notation string using the `decimal` module using that we can convert a float to scientific string notation of fixed string length as follows

```
def toSciNotation(num, leng):
    decimal = Decimal(num)
    length = len('%.0e' % decimal) + 1
    return f'%.{leng-length}e' % decimal
```

however if you are not expecting numbers that are larger than `1e+100` or smaller than `1e-100` you can simply the function to the following

```
def toSciNotation(num, leng):
    decimal = Decimal(num)
    return f'%.{leng}e' % decimal
```

we can than write all the scientific numbers to a list adding a space after each one and a `\n` to every fifth. However since our function can not handle negative values we need to pass an absolute and rectify the signage later. this Could be done as follows:

```
def toTable(num, leng, ID):
    sign = " " if num >= 0 else "-"
    out = sign + toSciNotation(abs(num), leng)
    if ID % 5 == 0:
        return out + "\n"
    return out + " "

def toStr(inp, leng):
    nums = [toTable(inp[i], leng-6, i+1) for i in range(len(inp))]
    return "".join(nums)
```

running this gives us the following string

```
-9.0000e+00 -8.0000e+00 -7.0000e+00 -6.0000e+00 -5.0000e+00
-4.0000e+00 -3.0000e+00 -2.0000e+00 -1.0000e+00  0.0000e+00
 1.0000e+00  2.0000e+00  3.0000e+00  4.0000e+00  5.0000e+00
 6.0000e+00  7.0000e+00  8.0000e+00  9.0000e+00  1.0000e+01
```

which can than be written to file.

Comment: I'm operating under the assumption that `-9.00e+00` is valid. if not I'll rectify it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer--it works well! I was originally trying to do this in a more direct fashion using common 3rd party libraries (e.g. Pandas), but could not find a straightforward way of accomplishing the above without resorting to element-wise manipulation (much like you have done here).